# her: a determiner or a pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, parts-of-speech, determiners

*Her* has two forms:

1. **Possessive form of 'she'**: *This is her pen*; *She is her mother*
2. **Object form of 'she'**: *Give it to her*; *I know her*

For simplicity, please let me refer to the first form of *her* as *possessive she* and the second form of *she* as *object she*.

The *object she* is surely a pronoun. But the case of *possessive she* is confusing.

The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says that *possessive she* is a determiner, whereas *Swan's Practical English Usage* says that *possessive she* is both a pronoun and a determiner.

I am confused. Is *possessive she* both a determiner and a pronoun? or is it only a determiner? If it it both, why does the LDCE define it only as a determiner?

Comment: Yes, it's both. It's a pronoun because it's coreferential with some other noun phrase, and it's a determiner because it fills the determiner slot in the noun phrase. For instance, we can say _her brother_ or _one of her brothers_ or _a brother of hers_ but we can't say **a her brother*, because _a_ and _her_ can't both fill the same determiner slot.

Comment: Please could you give a link to the Longman entry? I Googled  **Longman possessive she** but didn't find the precise quote. Also could you give a link for Swan, thanks.

Comment: @JohnLawler, please also answer my last question.   And Dear chasly from UK the LDCE link is: http://www.ldoceonline.com/search/?q=her
I have Swan's book but not the link I am sorry. But you can read it in the entry number 441 of that book.

Comment: John Lawler outranks the LDCE (but can hardly say so himself). But he is always quick to point out that it's how words are used in sentences that's important, not shoehorning them into convenient / traditional / often unhelpful or even wrong word-classes.

Comment: If your last question is about why the LDCE did not say it was both, that's their business and I have no idea why they did that. Perhaps they use a theory of parts of speech that requires that every word belong to one and only one category, no matter how it's used. That seems silly, but many people actually believe it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. @JohnLawler I would want to get deeper into that thing, and wonder whether it is because of the parts-of-speech belief that LDCE did that.

Comment: the LDCE link is: ldoceonline.com/search/?q=her I have Swan's book but not the link I am sorry. But you can read it in the entry number 441 of the 3rd edition of that book. @chaslyfromUK

Answer (score 1):

If Wikipedia can be trusted, it appears that there is no clear consensus on this topic.

Wikipedia's [pronoun page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun#Possessive) says:

> Possessive pronouns are used to indicate possession (in a broad sense). Some occur as independent noun phrases: mine, yours, hers, ours, yours, theirs...Others must accompany a noun: my, your, her, our, your, their...Those of the second type have traditionally been described as possessive adjectives, and in more modern terminology as possessive determiners. The term "possessive pronoun" is sometimes restricted to the first type.

The [possessive determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_determiner) page also seems to suggest a disagreement:

> The words my, your, etc. are sometimes classified, along with mine, yours etc., as possessive pronouns or genitive pronouns, since they are the possessive (or genitive) forms of the ordinary personal pronouns I, you etc. However, unlike most other pronouns, they do not behave grammatically as stand-alone nouns, but instead qualify another noun...

My *personal* opinion is that if possessive determiners don't stand alone as nouns, then they are just determiners and not pronouns.

Answer (score 0):

In traditional grammar "her" is a possessive adjective (her father) and a personal pronoun (I love her). Today some prefer to say it is a determiner and a personal pronoun. What real information do you get with determiner?
It says you can use the word as subelement before a noun. That's a relatively vague information.

By the way Longman's DCE has two entries: her no. 1 (in my terminology possessive adjective) and her no. 2 (pronoun, object form).

Comment: The important thing about determiners is that any noun only can have one determiner. So you can't say *the my sister* or *a my sister*, the way they do in Italian.

Comment: I knew this since my schooldays that you don't say "the my father". That was 50 years before I ever heard the word determiner. And the term raises so many questions that one may ask whether the term helps understanding.

Comment: But if you spoke Italian, you could. So maybe it's a necessary word (although determiners do seem to work the same in German and English).

Comment: I think il padre mio is something else. And deterniner doesn't help to understand Italian.

Comment: If you don't believe me, go to Google Translate and check that it turns *"Take my pen."* to *"Prendi la mia penna."* — literally *"Take the my pen".* Of course, maybe you don't need the concept of a determiner to explain this.

Comment: How does determiner help with la mia penna?

Comment: The explanation is that possessive adjectives like *mia* aren't determiners in Italian, although they are in German, French and English.

Comment: And how exactly does calling it an adjective help with understanding? You can't say _a my pen_ the way you can say _a blue pen_; you can't say _the pen is my_ the way you can say _the pen is blue_; you can't put _my_ in the comparative or superlative like you generally can with adjectives. Apart from the completely useless description of “it can come before a noun”, possessive determiners have basically nothing in common with adjectives. Plus, the term _determiner_ doesn't raise any more questions than any other term for a part of speech.

Comment: I don't subscribe to the definition of determiner which depends solely on distribution. There is a more fundamental difference between a determiner and an adjective: 'A determiner (/determinative) is a word, phrase or affix that occurs together with a noun or noun phrase and serves to express the reference of that noun or noun phrase in the context. That is, a determiner may indicate whether the noun is referring to a definite or indefinite element of a class, to a closer or more distant element, to an element belonging to a specified person or thing, to a particular number or quantity, etc.'

Comment: ...[ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner)] 'Yellow' in 'a yellow jumper' gives further information about the jumper as a self-contained item; 'that' in 'that jumper' specifies the jumper's relationship to the rest of the Universe (to some degree).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few arguments for considering *his, her, their, its* etc to be pronouns.

- They can be used as the subjects of gerunds.
- They can be used to replace the possessive construction "*[noun phrase]'s*": for example, we can replace "the spider's legs" with "its legs". "The spider's" is not typically analyzed as an adjective, and while it plays the *grammatical role* of "determiner" or "determinative", the *part of speech* of "the spider's" is typically analyzed as "noun phrase" (inflected for the possessive/genitive—although the *-'s* suffix is difficult to analyze and its exact nature has been debated). If we analyze "its" the same way, we can conclude that it is standing for a genitive/possessive noun phrase, so it is a genitive/possessive pronoun.

I don't think the terminology matters that much though.